# Assertion failure in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm building a UITableView app (SplitViewController) from a Single view application. I took some of the code from a Master Detail template application I created just to have something to build on, but the code that adds a new item results in this:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _objects.count;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

Debug window:

```
2014-05-18 01:49:21.755 myApp[1029:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1176
2014-05-18 01:49:30.858 myApp[1029:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
```

**But I have set the numberOfSectionsinTableView method to return 1**

Breakpoint code:

```
{
if (!_objects) {
    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at your (incorrect) implementation of the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. The problem should be obvious.

Comment: As a matter of fact I've actually gone through it - believe it or not. But all the help I get is that the problem should be obvious. If it was obvious for me I wouldn't post a question. Talking about de-motivating people

Comment: You fixed the code with your edit. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: the bad formatting doesn't motivate me to read the code. Talking about demotivating people.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I'm still having the problem. I just come here and the first things I hear is either that the problem is obvious (perhaps for you) or that the formatting is wrong, the grammar is wrong. Always something wrong.

Comment: sorry Erik, but if you don't want to help us help you why do u ask for help in the first place?

Comment: I definitely want help, thats all I want. But I feel there's always something wrong about the questions asked. I'm formatting my best and coding my best:)

Comment: Your original code was hardcoded to return `0` in your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method. That is obviously incorrect. You have now updated your code so it shows a more correct return value. And you have now confirmed that the problem still exists. So now people can start to offer help.

Comment: just preserve the formatting form the IDE.

Comment: Yeah. Agree. Let's start over with blank papers

Comment: The updated code should not be causing the problem. You alloc/init the `_objects` array. You add an object to `_objects`. You insert a corresponding row in the table view. Your data source methods appear to return the correct results. I don't see the problem. Assuming your real code matches the posted code, it should work. Using the debugger, verify that `_objects` has one object in it just before calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. Also ensure that `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 1 at that point.

Comment: Looks good, the debugger says this though: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: That's a whole different issue now.

Comment: I noticed it now going through the debugger

Comment: Is this your first table view? Have you tried a tutorial?

Comment: Yeah it's my first, but the tutorials I've tried didn't really fit my project. I've built this app in c#, so it's the new platform that's so tricky

Comment: Use a tutorial. TableViews are not simple things.

Comment: Yeah, trying to do that as far as it'll work with my app - but I really need help on this problem. Can't recreate the app now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my solution, according to the documentation:

**Important: You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.**

```
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```